# SQL Exception Timeout: Does the query complete?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a C# application that connects to the SQL Server and calls a stored procedure on a SQL Server database and throws:

> Timeout expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The statement has been terminated.

If the stored procedure is running without issue but takes longer than the timeout value, will the database continue to run it to completion or because the connection is ended will the database kill the query?

Comment: Notice `The statement has been terminated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SQL Server will rollback if the connection is lost. SQL Server relies
>   on the underlying network stack to report loss of connection, for
>   instace the TCP prototol if you are using IP. If TCP reports loss of
>   session, then SQL Server will use the information logged in the .ldf
>   file to rollback the transaction. If the client app does a timeout,
>   then an explicit signal is sent to the database engine, called
>   "attention", to terminate the session, and SQL Server will rollback
>   the transaction.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f55a9fe-b47f-4dfb-8aa6-0e25331a0989/transaction-rollback-on-connection-failure-or-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout will be managed by the client, in this case probably ADO.NET (or other).

After n seconds, the client sends a cancel message to the server, and the server cancels the query.